# What are the ways to provide authorization(Oauth 2.0) for the user in JIRA SOFTWARE TOOL?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, python-jira

Following are the steps I had followed:
1. Make project through Jira.
2. Followed all the steps and got autharization url.
3. now able to access access_token and refresh_token.

Problem:
In oauth 2.0 from one admin client id and client secret we can authorize multiple accounts registered with JIRA Software.
But I am not able to do this. I am not able to authorize the the users as what I did while integrating my project with google services like task, sheet, contacts etc.

I will be providing redirect code:
(I made a redirect api and registered its url in the setting tab)

```
class redirect(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        code = request.GET['code']
        headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }

        data = {"grant_type": "authorization_code", "client_id": "gJZQ66IW6h7ubMTnFuJmR5EnWgYEyadK",
                "client_secret": "KA2gCS80bjaNp-plqZ9twafqhyiuDeTYWGx6WByjNHsnGEHVPC5JFByC4ubGpVfU", "code": code,
                "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:8000/bug/redirect"}
        response = requests.post('https://auth.atlassian.com/oauth/token', headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
        # access_token = response.json()['access_token']
        refresh_token = response.json()['refresh_token']

        header = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }

        access_token = response.json()['access_token']
        import pdb
        pdb.set_trace()

        headers = {
            'Authorization': access_token,
            'Accept': 'application/json',
        }

        response = requests.get('https://api.atlassian.com/oauth/token/accessible-resources', headers=headers)
        return JsonResponse({'response': response.json()})
```

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fwb0F8y5BHB7nhJIgSaTfYRMHXLEKc5G/view?usp=sharing

Comment: pls go through this pic.